# Selecting a single row in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am using MySQL, I have a table that has 9 columns.  One of them is the primary key.

How can I select a single row, by the primary key or column 8 or 4?

Comment: select a single row: `select * from yourtable limit 1;`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 123 OR colname4 = 'x' OR colname8 = 'y' LIMIT 1
```

The ['LIMIT' keyword](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) makes sure there is only one row returned.

Comment: However, "MySQL does not support LIMIT in subqueries for certain subquery operators". Please see [Restrictions on Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-restrictions.html).

Comment: Oh this made my code so much faster, I knew there was this keyword but I just forgot about it! Thank you so much! Now I don't need to fetch all the values and just get the first returned row. :>

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from MyTable
where MyPrimaryKey = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Columns in SQL don't have a defined 'order'. Database systems generally keep track of an order for display purposes, but it doesn't make sense to ask a database to select a column by number. You need to know the column's name in order to query its contents.

The same thing goes for the primary key (which, incidentally, may not be just a single column). You have to know which column it is, and what that column is named, in order to execute a query.

If you don't know these things, or need to figure them out dynamically, then

```
DESCRIBE tablename;
```

will tell you the names of each column, and whether it is part of the primary key or not. It will return a table that you can read, like any other result.