# Needing only 1 row from PHP MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm sure I've done this in the past, but it's a few years ago and I don't remember how it's done and the online tutorials aren't helping.

I have a MySQL database. It has 1 table in it called 'data'. In the 'data' table, there are about 15,000 rows, and 31 columns. I need to extract the data from only 1 of these rows, based on a lookup referencing the string in column 1. When the mysql query finds the correct row, I need every single item read into variables that I can show on my page.

I believe this line is the problem:

```
$sql = "SELECT Mark,Manufacturer,Model FROM data";
```

Could someone please let me know what it needs to be changed to, to get the desired result? TIA! :)

Comment: use `limit` for this

Comment: `WHERE` is your friend. If you did not find that in online tutorials I wonder where you have been looking :)

Comment: @chiragsatapara No, use a `where <column1name> = <desiredvalue>`; if that still returns more than one row (which shouldn't happen for PK's) you might consider a `limit` but only if adding more to the `where` expression doesn't help.

Comment: This question is badly reasearched. Use Google and type in "mysql select only one row from database", the second result brings up this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412682/7008354. Also, if you want to get a row matching specific conditions, use the `WHERE` keyword as suggested (in Combination with `LIMIT` if there may be multiple matching rows and you only wnat to get the frist one).

Comment: Data is a very poor table name...

Comment: fvu: Looking on W3Schools, but WHERE is only showing up in MySQL's UPDATE option.

TobiasF.: Maybe badly researched question, but doing this on very little sleep...

jarlh: What should I rename it to? It's a table, and has data in it. At least I know what it's referring to, and nobody else is going to be seeing it.

Comment: @JaceG [w3schools may have it flaws, but they have a page **dedicated** to where](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp). So, poorly resarched question is an appropriate description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set options of select query

```
$sql = "SELECT Mark,Manufacturer,Model FROM data WHERE Model (or manufacturer,mark) = 'some text'";
```

Comment: this assumes the column is `UNIQUE`, otherwise the query may return multiple rows.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg yes you are right. İ just thought this was what he wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

As my colleges have Explained "where' is your friend!

So you can always query as follows :

```
Select * from Data
Where column_1 = 'Your Desired String'
```

Alternatively you could use

```
 Select Discinct Limit 1 Mark,Manufacturer,Model FROM data
 Order By Mark Asc
```