# how to select a single row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have successfully created (with the help of a tutorial) a CRUD database application. I’m able to easily create, read and edit data from my table. I would like to change how it reads. I want it to select one row only because using this code from the tutorial, it displays all the records in the table ordered by id.
How can I make it select one record only (based on time I possible)

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM time_table";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
{
?>
```

Comment: Do an internet search on some SQL tutorials. Stack Overflow is for helping answer questions when you are having a specific problem, not a tutorial/training/tutoring site. If you are in a hurry, search the internet for "SQL" and "WHERE" clauses.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Did you see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1412682/1425697) by @christophed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting a single row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412665/selecting-a-single-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using LIMIT in mysql you can decide how many rows you want to fetch.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM time_table LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: order by must be used as well

Comment: It is not necessary to use order by as well. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause/

Comment: if you want a specific row ordering is a must, if you don't care then sure leave it out. My point was intended to prompt you to elaborate for someone who needs more assistance than just the bare minimum